# python/jython NameError

Tags: python, jython

im facing typical NameError (without any additional message) on command "cd" while importing other file.

E.g. **executor.py**

```
import sys
from java.lang import System
import ds_update

x = ds_update.DataSource()
x.someAction()
```

And **ds_update.py**
import sys
from java.lang import System

```
import sys
from java.lang import System

class DataSource:

  def someAction(self): 
    try:
      cd('/')
    ...
```

Got error: (if those commands are in one file, there is no problem with cd)

```
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "...\executor.py", line 17, in ?
  File "...\ds_update.py", line 11, in updateDS
NameError: cd
```

Thank you:-)

Comment: You're trying to call a function that doesn't exist, namely `cd()`, i think the function you're looking for is `os.chdir()`

Comment: I think that problem is that im calling WLST (weblogic scripting tool) via Jython (almost python) and this one has its own set of methods including cd. because if this is in one file, it works with cd. What im invoking is java weblogic.WLST executor.py

Comment: I never used `Jython` nor `WLST`, but you have to import these methods in your script to be able to use them.

Comment: it seems that this tool adds some custom imports to passed script and that's why I don't know cd. It seems I will have to all use it in one file unless i find out which imports are used

Comment: ok, im marking this thread as solved... thanks all

Comment: @dxxx You can't mark it as solved when there are no answers posted.

Comment: @MatToufoutu Why don't you post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use a function that isn't defined, namely `cd()`, according to your comments, it is something provided by `WLST`. I never used `Jython` nor `WLST`, but you have to find a way to import these methods in your script to be able to use them.

Answer (score 2):

there are a few imports needed, namely at least:

import wl

the way to generate the wl module is described by Oracle here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/using_WLST.html#wp1094333

then you should prefix with "wl." all your "cd" and other WLST built-in commands.

you will find more here

http://www.javamonamour.org/2013/08/wlst-nameerror-cd.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is old, I want to add this:

WLST uses a type of namespace. because of this, functions pertaining to wlst don't work if you put the to-be-imported-files not in /wlserver_10.3/common/wlst